# List in python not working where command are passed as string

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

This is the sequence of input given and we have to make a List to go thought the above commands which will be given by the user as input.

```
12
insert 0 5
insert 1 10
insert 0 6
print 
remove 6
append 9
append 1
sort 
print
pop
reverse
print
```

The result of the following operations should be like this-

> [6, 5, 10]
>   [1, 5, 9, 10]
>   [9, 5, 1]

The following code will read the commands given as text where the first line will be the total no of commands that have to be followed and the following command will be the given as text.But the code is not working for me it is not printing out anything. why it is so? please provide solution to this problem.

```
L=[]
li=[]
def check(string):
for a in string:
    if a=='insert':
        li=string.split()
        L.insert(int(li[1]),int(li[2]))
        li=[]
    elif(a=='append'):
        li=string.split()
        L.append(int(li[1]))
        li=[]
    elif(a=='sort'):
        L.sort()
    elif(a=='remove'):
        li=string.split()
        L.remove(li[1])
        li=[]
    elif(a=='print'):
        print(L) 
    elif(a=='reverse'):
        L.reverse()
    elif a=='pop':
        L=L[:-2]
    else:
        pass
N=int(input(""))
for i in range(N):
    string =str(input(""))
    check(string)
```

Comment: It looks like the code 'for a in string' loop at method check(), iterates over each letter of the string, so no actions are performed... it always do 'pass'

Comment: debug. look at the content of your variables. in particular `a`.

Comment: Probably for pop you will want use `L[:-1]` or `L.pop()`, however the latter can result with an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code `for a in string` loop at method `check()`, iterates over each letter of the string, so no actions are performed... it always do 'pass'.

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(string,L,li):
    for a in map(str,string.split()):
            if a =='insert':
                li=string.split()
                L.insert(int(li[1]),int(li[2]))
                li=[]
            elif(a=='append'):
                li=string.split()
                L.append(int(li[1]))
                li=[]
            elif(a=='sort'):
                L.sort()
            elif(a=='remove'):
                li=string.split()
                L.remove(li[1])
                li=[]
            elif(a=='print'):
                print(L) 
            elif(a=='reverse'):
                L.reverse()
            elif a=='pop':
                L=L[:-2]
        else:
                pass
        break
N=int(input(""))
L = []
li = []
for i in range(N):
    string =raw_input("")
check(string,L,li)
```